# This site can’t be reached

Tags: apache2, webapps, webmin, dotnet

I am on Ubuntu hosting a .NET 6 web app. If I go to the directory where the publish files are stored and run command `dotnet webapp.dll`, then I will get something like the output below (Then if I go to the browser and look at the website example.com, the webapp displays fine)

```
Feb 09 20:52:15 ubuntu dotnet-webapp[2687]:       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Feb 09 20:52:15 ubuntu dotnet-webapp[2687]:       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Feb 09 20:52:15 ubuntu dotnet-webapp[2687]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Feb 09 20:52:15 ubuntu dotnet-webapp[2687]:       Hosting environment: Production
```

But if I create a service and enable it, I see that the output above displays if I run the `command: sudo journalctl -fu webapp.service`
However, example.com says "This site can’t be reached"
Would like some help please.

Config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName company.com
   ServerAdmin admin.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/company.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On  
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/ 
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/  
   RewriteEngine on  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]  
   RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P]  
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-company.com.log  
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-company.com.log combined  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Desktop or Server?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry PI. Port 80 is opened and I have a proxy for port 80 to http://localhost:5000. ( I added my config file to my question description)